# Error: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I'm pretty new to R. I'm trying to train my data for a logistic regression. When trying to build the logistic regression model, I am only using numerical values but keep getting the following error.

Warning message:
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

As I said, pretty new.

This is what I've tried to far.

```
AllMortgage$default <- as.factor(AllMortgage$default)
smp_size <- floor(0.70 * nrow(AllMortgage))
set.seed(12345)
trainindex <- sample(seq_len(nrow(AllMortgage)), size = smp_size)
training <- AllMortgage[trainindex,]
validation <- AllMortgage[-trainindex,]

str(training)

mylogit<-glm(default ~ credit_score + cltv + dti_ratio + upb + ltv + interest_rate + loan_term + num_borrowers,
             data=training, family=binomial)
summary(mylogit)
```

And if I continue building, I get the following error:

`mylogit.probs<-predict(mylogit,validation,type="response")`

Warning message:
'newdata' had 62537 rows but variables found have 208454 rows

some sample data below. there are about 208563 rows.

```
ID  loan_seq_number delincuency_status  credit_score    fthb    mi_perc units   occupancy   cltv    dti_ratio   upb ltv interest_rate   channel ppm state   property_type   postal_code loan_purpose    loan_term   num_borrowers   super_conforming    default
1   F108Q4000001    0   736 N   0   1   P   80  20  172000  80  6.25    R   N   MI  SF  49700   C   360 2   N   0
2   F108Q4000002    0   797 N   0   1   P   62  31  215000  62  5.625   C   N   ME  SF  4000    N   360 1   N   0
3   F108Q4000003    0   804 N   0   1   P   91  53  220000  80  5.5 R   N   MN  SF  55000   N   360 2   N   0
4   F108Q4000004    0   803 N   0   1   P   86  46  288000  76  5.5 R   N   IL  SF  61300   N   360 1   N   0
5   F108Q4000005    0   803 N   0   1   P   36  17  58000   36  4.875   R   N   WI  SF  54800   N   360 1   N   0
6   F108Q4000006    4   666 N   0   1   P   53  64  125000  53  6.625   R   N   GA  SF  30200   N   360 2   N   0
7   F108Q4000007    1   677 N   0   1   P   34  19  55000   34  5.25    R   N   KY  SF  42300   N   360 2   N   0
8   F108Q4000008    0   755 N   0   1   P   73  35  410000  73  5.875   R   N   CO  SF  81200   N   360 2   N   0
9   F108Q4000009    0   768 N   0   1   P   80  32  214000  80  5.5 R   N   MI  SF  49700   N   360 2   N   0
10  F108Q4000010    0   776 N   0   1   P   49  44  164000  49  6   R   N   MO  SF  63300   N   360 2   N   0
11  F108Q4000011    1   660 N   0   1   P   80  27  53000   80  7.125   R   N   MI  SF  49700   N   360 2   N   0
12  F108Q4000012    0   813 N   25  1   P   86  27  417000  86  5.875   R   N   IL  SF  62400   N   360 2   N   0
13  F108Q4000013    0   773 N   0   1   P   75  30  98000   75  5.875   R   N   MN  SF  56000   N   360 1   N   0
14  F108Q4000014    0   735 N   0   1   P   80  15  240000  80  6.5 R   N   IL  SF  61400   C   360 2   N   0
15  F108Q4000015    2   610 N   0   1   P   80  48  220000  80  8.25    R   Y   IL  SF  62600   C   360 2   N   0
16  F108Q4000016    0   688 N   30  1   P   95  42  71000   95  6.25    R   N   IA  SF  50500   P   360 1   N   0
17  F108Q4000017    0   737 N   0   1   P   79  28  357000  79  6.125   R   N   KS  SF  66500   N   360 2   N   0
18  F108Q4000018    0   672 N   0   1   P   73  40  60000   73  6.875   R   N   KS  SF  66500   N   360 1   N   0
19  F108Q4000019    0   748 Y   0   1   P   80  28  140000  80  6.375   R   N   MI  SF  48400   P   360 2   N   0
20  F108Q4000020    0   801 N   0   1   P   67  34  417000  67  6.25    R   N   MD  SF  20600   C   360 1   N   0
21  F108Q4000021    0   785 N   0   1   P   79  25  55000   79  6.75    R   N   NY  SF  14800   C   360 1   N   0
22  F108Q4000022    2   674 N   0   1   P   80  38  300000  80  6.875   R   N   CO  SF  81200   N   360 2   N   0
23  F108Q4000023    0   745 N   0   1   P   60  33  160000  60  5.5 R   N   WY  SF  82400   N   360 2   N   0
24  F108Q4000024    0   753 N   0   1   I   68  58  68000   68  7.375   R   N   MO  PU  64100   C   360 1   N   0
25  F108Q4000025    0   669 N   0   1   P   72  15  80000   72  5.875   R   Y   GA  SF  30200   C   360 1   N   0
26  F108Q4000026    0   772 9   0   1   P   79  38  417000  79  5.875   R   N   IL  SF  62400   N   360 2   N   0
27  F108Q4000027    0   706 N   0   1   P   56  40  70000   56  7.75    R   N   IL  MH  62800   P   360 1   N   0
28  F108Q4000028    0   754 N   0   1   P   42  43  61000   42  6.625   R   N   KY  SF  42100   N   360 2   N   0
29  F108Q4000029    0   751 N   0   1   P   31  39  23000   31  6.625   R   N   KY  SF  42100   P   360 1   N   0
30  F108Q4000030    0   771 N   30  1   P   92  37  210000  92  6.5 R   N   TX  SF  77600   N   360 2   N   0
31  F108Q4000031    0   749 N   0   1   P   76  30  140000  76  6.75    R   N   KS  SF  66700   N   360 2   N   0
32  F108Q4000032    0   791 N   12  1   S   84  29  100000  84  6.625   R   N   MI  SF  49600   P   360 1   N   0
33  F108Q4000033    0   743 Y   30  1   P   95  43  118000  95  6.125   R   N   GA  SF  30200   P   360 1   N   0
34  F108Q4000034    0   794 N   0   1   P   80  28  106000  80  6.625   R   N   NC  SF  27200   C   360 1   N   0
35  F108Q4000035    3   771 N   0   4   I   65  50  285000  65  6.625   R   Y   CT  SF  6600    N   360 1   N   0
36  F108Q4000036    0   799 N   0   2   P   29  57  417000  29  6.125   R   N   CA  SF  94100   N   360 2   N   0
37  F108Q4000037    29  706 Y   0   1   P   80  48  73000   80  6.625   C   N   ME  SF  4400    P   360 1   N   1
38  F108Q4000038    0   806 N   0   1   P   60  22  80000   60  6.375   R   N   WA  CO  98800   C   360 1   N   0
39  F108Q4000039    0   657 N   0   1   P   78  15  132000  78  6.5 R   N   WA  SF  98800   P   360 2   N   0
40  F108Q4000040    0   756 N   0   1   P   80  21  176000  80  6.25    R   N   MN  SF  56000   P   360 2   N   0
41  F108Q4000041    0   754 N   30  1   P   95  44  285000  95  6.625   R   N   NY  SF  12100   P   360 2   N   0
42  F108Q4000042    0   785 N   0   1   P   47  6   150000  47  6.5 R   N   CO  SF  81200   C   360 1   N   0
43  F108Q4000043    0   694 N   0   1   P   67  38  138000  67  6.75    R   N   MO  SF  63700   N   360 1   N   0
44  F108Q4000044    0   688 N   30  1   P   95  42  297000  95  6.5 R   Y   AK  SF  99900   P   360 1   N   0
45  F108Q4000045    0   708 N   0   1   P   80  34  116000  80  6.875   R   N   KS  SF  66500   C   360 2   N   0
46  F108Q4000046    0   775 N   0   1   P   74  39  251000  74  6.625   R   Y   NC  SF  27800   C   360 1   N   0
47  F108Q4000047    1   687 N   0   1   P   80  57  186000  80  6.75    R   Y   OH  SF  43500   N   360 1   N   0
48  F108Q4000048    0   804 N   0   1   S   49  11  209000  49  6.75    R   N   NJ  CO  8200    P   360 2   N   0
49  F108Q4000049    0   809 N   0   1   P   37  30  100000  37  6.625   C   N   OR  SF  97200   C   360 1   N   0
50  F108Q4000050    1   734 N   0   1   P   80  20  34000   80  6.625   R   N   SC  SF  29300   P   360 1   N   0
51  F108Q4000051    0   649 Y   30  1   P   95  27  87000   95  6.625   R   N   PA  SF  16900   P   360 2   N   0
52  F108Q4000052    0   772 N   0   1   P   73  16  78000   73  6.5 R   N   KY  SF  42500   C   360 1   N   0
53  F108Q4000053    0   799 N   0   1   P   54  21  105000  54  6.875   R   N   PA  SF  18000   C   360 1   N   0
54  F108Q4000054    0   677 N   0   1   P   80  35  191000  80  6.5 R   N   NY  SF  14000   P   360 2   N   0
55  F108Q4000055    0   775 N   0   1   I   80  31  186000  80  6.875   R   Y   CA  SF  93200   C   360 2   N   0
56  F108Q4000056    0   768 N   30  1   P   92  20  290000  92  6.25    R   N   KS  SF  66500   N   360 2   N   0
57  F108Q4000057    19  685 N   0   1   P   80  35  144000  80  6.5 R   N   NV  SF  89100   C   360 1   N   1
58  F108Q4000058    0   623 N   0   1   P   59  38  56000   59  6.5 R   N   KY  SF  42100   C   360 1   N   0
59  F108Q4000059    0   628 N   0   1   P   75  43  338000  75  7   C   Y   KS  SF  66400   C   360 2   N   0
60  F108Q4000060    0   710 N   0   1   P   58  25  107000  58  6.5 R   N   ND  SF  58800   C   360 1   N   0
61  F108Q4000061    0   740 Y   30  1   P   95  47  349000  95  6.625   R   N   NY  SF  12500   P   360 1   N   0
62  F108Q4000062    0   767 N   0   1   P   66  44  294000  66  6.25    R   N   WA  SF  98900   N   360 2   N   0
63  F108Q4000063    0   745 N   0   1   P   79  20  65000   79  7.25    R   N   MO  SF  64000   C   360 2   N   0
64  F108Q4000064    0   773 N   25  1   P   87  50  154000  87  6.25    R   N   ND  SF  58400   P   360 1   N   0
65  F108Q4000065    0   732 N   30  1   P   90  28  149000  90  6.75    R   N   ME  SF  4600    P   360 1   N   0
66  F108Q4000066    0   702 N   0   1   P   73  38  133000  73  6.375   R   N   MI  SF  49300   C   360 2   N   0
67  F108Q4000067    0   780 N   0   1   P   80  39  135000  80  6.375   R   N   ND  SF  58800   P   360 2   N   0
68  F108Q4000068    0   780 Y   0   1   P   76  22  125000  76  6.75    R   N   IL  SF  61500   P   360 2   N   0
69  F108Q4000069    0   746 N   0   1   P   21  17  60000   21  6.625   R   N   NC  SF  28600   C   360 2   N   0
70  F108Q4000070    0   678 N   0   1   P   94  46  168000  80  6.375   R   N   AK  SF  99500   N   360 1   N   0
71  F108Q4000071    0   746 N   30  1   S   95  25  76000   95  6.625   R   N   MI  SF  49400   P   360 2   N   0
72  F108Q4000072    0   807 N   0   1   P   73  49  145000  73  6.625   R   N   MO  SF  65700   C   360 1   N   0
73  F108Q4000073    4   746 N   0   1   P   74  29  150000  74  6.5 R   N   CA  SF  96000   C   360 1   N   0
74  F108Q4000074    0   734 Y   30  1   P   95  18  109000  95  6.25    R   N   GA  SF  30200   P   360 2   N   0
75  F108Q4000075    0   692 N   25  1   P   90  28  198000  90  6.5 C   N   WI  SF  53900   P   360 2   N   0
76  F108Q4000076    0   788 Y   0   1   P   80  27  30000   80  6.375   R   N   KY  SF  42100   P   360 2   N   0
77  F108Q4000077    0   657 N   0   1   P   18  38  225000  18  6.125   R   N   CA  SF  93400   C   360 2   N   0
78  F108Q4000078    0   788 9   0   1   P   69  26  130000  69  6.625   R   N   NY  SF  12700   C   360 1   N   0
79  F108Q4000079    0   662 N   0   1   P   80  55  183000  80  6.75    R   Y   ME  SF  4900    P   360 1   N   0
80  F108Q4000080    0   717 Y   30  1   P   95  41  126000  95  6.5 R   N   TX  SF  75600   P   360 1   N   0
81  F108Q4000081    0   796 N   0   1   P   55  39  90000   55  6.25    R   N   NC  SF  27400   C   360 1   N   0
82  F108Q4000082    0   710 N   0   1   P   48  45  120000  48  6.625   R   N   WA  SF  98800   C   360 1   N   0
83  F108Q4000083    0   741 N   0   1   P   90  20  183000  80  5.875   C   N   VT  SF  5400    P   360 2   N   0
84  F108Q4000084    0   807 N   0   1   P   33  8   200000  17  6.125   R   N   IL  SF  60500   N   360 2   N   0
85  F108Q4000085    0   727 N   0   1   S   80  39  88000   80  6.375   R   N   KY  SF  42500   P   360 2   N   0
86  F108Q4000086    0   768 N   0   1   P   69  31  197000  69  5.75    R   N   CO  PU  81200   N   360 2   N   0
87  F108Q4000087    15  626 Y   30  1   P   95  21  84000   95  8.25    R   Y   IA  SF  52600   P   360 1   N   1
88  F108Q4000088    0   793 N   30  1   P   92  29  218000  92  6.25    R   N   TX  SF  77600   N   360 2   N   0
89  F108Q4000089    0   684 N   0   1   P   70  30  118000  70  6.5 R   N   MI  SF  49300   C   360 2   N   0
90  F108Q4000090    0   756 N   0   1   P   80  29  73000   80  6.375   R   N   MI  SF  48600   C   360 2   N   0
91  F108Q4000091    2   652 N   0   1   P   79  40  251000  79  6.75    R   N   TX  SF  77600   N   360 2   N   0
92  F108Q4000092    0   688 N   0   1   P   72  48  150000  72  6.5 R   N   KY  SF  42100   P   360 1   N   0
93  F108Q4000093    0   759 N   12  1   P   85  43  86000   85  6.375   R   N   NY  SF  14800   P   360 1   N   0
94  F108Q4000094    0   756 N   0   1   P   80  35  260000  80  5.875   R   N   ND  SF  58500   N   360 2   N   0
95  F108Q4000095    0   746 N   0   2   P   33  51  363000  33  6.5 R   N   NY  SF  11200   C   360 2   N   0
96  F108Q4000096    0   719 N   0   1   P   80  22  152000  80  5.875   R   N   OK  SF  74800   P   360 2   N   0
97  F108Q4000097    0   758 N   30  1   P   94  32  264000  94  6.375   R   N   IL  SF  62200   P   360 2   N   0
98  F108Q4000098    1   743 N   0   1   P   80  48  154000  80  6.25    R   N   NC  SF  27300   C   360 2   N   0
99  F108Q4000099    0   678 N   0   1   P   80  31  109000  80  6.375   R   N   MI  SF  49600   N   360 2   N   0
100 F108Q4000100    0   718 N   0   1   P   80  38  120000  80  6.25    R   N   NC  SF  27500   N   360 1   N   0
101 F108Q4000101    1   665 N   0   1   P   47  23  243000  47  6.375   R   Y   IL  SF  60400   C   360 1   N   0
102 F108Q4000102    0   761 Y   0   1   P   83  12  139000  80  6   R   N   MN  SF  56500   P   360 2   N   0
103 F108Q4000103    0   794 N   0   1   I   80  28  85000   80  6.375   R   N   IA  SF  52600   P   360 2   N   0
104 F108Q4000104    0   747 N   30  1   P   95  50  206000  95  6   R   N   ND  SF  58500   P   360 2   N   0
105 F108Q4000105    1   702 N   0   1   P   80  33  348000  80  6.375   R   N   NY  SF  12200   P   360 1   N   0
106 F108Q4000106    0   780 N   0   1   P   44  23  417000  44  6.25    R   N   MN  SF  55100   N   360 2   N   0
107 F108Q4000107    1   648 N   0   1   P   55  24  355000  55  6.125   R   N   WA  SF  98800   C   360 2   N   0
108 F108Q4000108    0   732 N   0   1   P   58  11  300000  58  5.75    R   N   NY  SF  14200   P   360 2   N   0
109 F108Q4000109    0   788 N   0   1   P   65  24  169000  65  5.875   R   Y   FL  PU  32300   P   360 1   N   0
110 F108Q4000110    0   787 N   0   1   S   49  26  130000  49  6   R   N   IA  SF  52100   C   360 2   N   0
111 F108Q4000111    2   696 N   0   1   P   80  32  343000  80  6.375   R   Y   UT  SF  84000   N   360 1   N   0
112 F108Q4000112    0   789 N   0   1   P   20  47  61000   20  6   R   Y   OH  SF  45000   N   360 2   N   0
113 F108Q4000113    0   774 N   25  1   P   90  48  284000  90  7   R   N   FL  PU  33000   P   360 1   N   0
114 F108Q4000114    0   645 N   0   1   P   58  38  220000  58  6.375   R   Y   AK  SF  99900   N   360 2   N   0
115 F108Q4000115    0   766 N   0   1   P   71  63  88000   71  6.25    R   N   MI  SF  48000   N   360 2   N   0
116 F108Q4000116    0   792 Y   0   1   P   77  22  130000  77  5.875   R   N   ND  SF  58800   P   360 2   N   0
117 F108Q4000117    0   812 N   0   1   P   78  42  255000  78  5.625   R   N   KY  SF  40300   C   360 2   N   0
118 F108Q4000118    0   697 N   0   1   P   75  19  94000   75  6   R   N   MI  SF  49000   C   360 2   N   0
119 F108Q4000119    1   605 N   0   1   S   70  35  243000  70  7.875   R   N   FL  CO  33000   C   360 1   N   0
120 F108Q4000120    0   709 Y   12  1   P   85  61  378000  85  6.625   R   N   NY  CO  10000   P   360 1   N   0
121 F108Q4000121    0   766 N   0   1   P   80  29  236000  80  6   R   N   CA  SF  96000   P   360 2   N   0
122 F108Q4000122    0   801 N   30  1   P   95  44  99000   95  6   R   N   OK  SF  73100   P   360 1   N   0
123 F108Q4000123    0   753 N   0   1   P   69  24  183000  69  6   R   N   NE  SF  68000   P   360 2   N   0
124 F108Q4000124    0   749 9   0   1   P   80  18  416000  80  6   R   N   IL  SF  61700   N   360 2   N   0
125 F108Q4000125    0   689 N   0   1   P   61  53  350000  61  6   R   N   IN  SF  46800   N   360 1   N   0
126 F108Q4000126    0   763 N   0   1   P   57  36  136000  57  5.875   R   N   IA  SF  52100   C   360 2   N   0
127 F108Q4000127    0   816 N   0   1   P   57  28  162000  57  5.5 R   N   CT  SF  6400    C   360 1   N   0
128 F108Q4000128    0   789 N   0   1   P   89  23  356000  80  5.875   R   N   IL  SF  60500   N   360 2   N   0
129 F108Q4000129    0   720 N   0   1   P   80  35  248000  80  6   R   N   VT  PU  5400    P   360 2   N   0
130 F108Q4000130    0   723 N   0   1   P   25  49  95000   25  5.75    R   Y   CO  SF  81100   N   360 2   N   0
131 F108Q4000131    0   710 Y   25  1   P   90  25  361000  90  6   R   N   NJ  SF  7700    P   360 1   N   0
132 F108Q4000132    0   809 N   0   1   P   54  39  105000  54  6.125   C   N   OR  SF  97200   C   360 1   N   0
133 F108Q4000133    0   646 N   0   1   P   66  24  205000  66  6   R   N   MA  SF  2100    C   360 2   N   0
134 F108Q4000134    0   776 Y   0   1   P   77  43  400000  77  5.875   R   N   CA  SF  92600   P   360 1   N   0
135 F108Q4000135    0   734 Y   30  1   P   95  35  142000  95  6   R   N   MN  SF  55300   P   360 1   N   0
136 F108Q4000136    0   797 N   0   1   P   90  33  140000  80  5.875   R   N   WI  SF  53700   N   360 2   N   0
137 F108Q4000137    0   528 N   0   1   P   63  21  67000   63  6.375   R   N   NY  SF  14800   P   360 2   N   0
138 F108Q4000138    0   790 N   0   1   P   80  55  204000  80  5.5 R   N   NY  SF  14800   P   360 2   N   0
139 F108Q4000139    0   757 N   0   1   P   61  58  475000  50  5.5 R   N   HI  SF  96800   N   360 2   N   0
140 F108Q4000140    0   699 Y   0   2   P   60  50  150000  60  6.5 R   N   MA  SF  2100    P   360 1   N   0
141 F108Q4000141    0   812 N   0   1   P   22  9   70000   22  5.875   R   N   MO  SF  63100   N   360 2   N   0
142 F108Q4000142    0   803 N   0   1   S   42  15  417000  42  5.875   R   N   MN  SF  55700   N   360 2   N   0
143 F108Q4000143    0   788 N   0   1   P   81  55  417000  44  6   R   N   KY  SF  40300   N   360 2   N   0
144 F108Q4000144    1   664 N   0   1   P   58  46  385000  58  6.125   R   N   NJ  SF  7600    C   360 1   N   0
145 F108Q4000145    0   768 N   0   1   P   80  47  319000  80  5.875   R   N   WI  SF  54000   N   360 2   N   0
146 F108Q4000146    0   808 N   0   1   P   44  29  83000   44  6.25    R   N   NY  SF  12500   C   360 1   N   0
147 F108Q4000147    0   764 N   0   1   P   80  22  154000  80  6   R   N   MI  SF  48600   P   360 2   N   0
148 F108Q4000148    0   798 N   0   1   P   73  20  255000  73  5.875   R   N   MN  SF  56600   N   360 2   N   0
149 F108Q4000149    0   816 N   0   1   P   33  15  48000   33  6   R   Y   IA  SF  50000   P   360 2   N   0
150 F108Q4000150    0   801 N   0   1   P   80  19  156000  80  6   R   N   NC  SF  28600   C   360 2   N   0
151 F108Q4000151    0   747 N   0   1   P   62  35  309000  62  5.5 R   N   WA  SF  98800   N   360 2   N   0
152 F108Q4000152    0   701 N   0   1   P   22  38  30000   22  6   R   N   IN  SF  46700   N   360 1   N   0
153 F108Q4000153    0   672 N   30  1   P   95  45  213000  95  6.25    R   Y   KY  SF  41200   P   360 1   N   0
154 F108Q4000154    0   691 N   0   1   P   71  51  165000  71  5.75    R   N   CO  SF  81200   N   360 2   N   0
155 F108Q4000155    0   766 N   0   1   P   69  47  175000  69  5.75    R   N   IL  SF  62400   N   360 1   N   0
156 F108Q4000156    0   789 N   0   1   P   80  45  120000  80  6   R   N   OH  SF  43300   P   360 2   N   0
157 F108Q4000157    0   742 N   0   1   P   93  27  299000  78  6.625   C   N   IN  SF  47900   N   360 2   N   0
158 F108Q4000158    0   733 N   0   1   P   79  40  173000  79  5.5 R   N   TN  SF  37100   N   360 2   N   0
159 F108Q4000159    0   756 N   0   1   P   66  28  150000  66  5.625   C   N   SC  SF  29000   C   360 2   N   0
160 F108Q4000160    0   653 N   0   1   P   80  48  142000  80  6   C   N   WI  SF  54400   N   360 2   N   0
161 F108Q4000161    0   707 N   0   1   P   80  31  156000  80  6.625   R   N   MD  SF  21900   P   360 2   N   0
162 F108Q4000162    0   773 9   0   1   P   63  33  179000  63  5.875   R   N   MI  SF  48000   N   324 2   N   0
163 F108Q4000163    0   696 N   0   1   P   80  33  92000   80  5.875   R   N   ME  SF  4600    P   360 2   N   0
164 F108Q4000164    0   678 N   0   1   P   90  30  344000  80  7   R   Y   MN  SF  55800   C   360 2   N   0
165 F108Q4000165    0   762 N   0   1   P   80  35  184000  80  5.875   R   N   KS  SF  67400   N   360 2   N   0
166 F108Q4000166    0   760 N   0   1   I   80  35  96000   80  6.875   R   N   KS  SF  67400   C   360 2   N   0
167 F108Q4000167    0   758 9   0   1   I   80  19  144000  80  5.875   R   N   OH  SF  45200   N   360 2   N   0
168 F108Q4000168    0   790 N   0   1   P   67  41  32000   67  6.25    R   N   KY  SF  42100   N   360 1   N   0
169 F108Q4000169    0   808 N   0   1   P   69  40  75000   69  5.875   R   N   MI  SF  49000   C   360 1   N   0
170 F108Q4000170    1   654 N   0   1   P   54  27  85000   54  6.375   R   N   MO  SF  65700   P   360 1   N   0
171 F108Q4000171    0   793 N   0   1   P   80  21  195000  80  6.375   R   N   IN  SF  47000   N   360 2   N   0
172 F108Q4000172    0   723 N   0   1   P   51  21  152000  51  6   R   N   IL  PU  60400   N   360 2   N   0
173 F108Q4000173    0   712 Y   0   1   P   80  33  92000   80  5.75    R   Y   PA  SF  17700   P   360 2   N   0
174 F108Q4000174    0   716 Y   0   1   P   75  44  415000  75  6   R   N   NJ  SF  8800    P   360 2   N   0
175 F108Q4000175    0   798 N   0   1   P   74  27  240000  74  6   R   N   KY  SF  42200   C   360 1   N   0
176 F108Q4000176    0   699 N   30  1   P   93  41  245000  93  5.75    R   N   ND  SF  58600   P   360 2   N   0
177 F108Q4000177    0   771 N   0   1   P   48  34  71000   48  6.125   R   N   MI  SF  49000   P   360 2   N   0
178 F108Q4000178    0   714 Y   30  1   P   95  39  125000  95  5.875   R   N   IA  SF  50300   P   360 2   N   0
179 F108Q4000179    0   816 Y   0   1   P   75  30  115000  75  5.875   R   N   WI  SF  53200   P   360 1   N   0
180 F108Q4000180    0   713 N   0   1   P   79  15  360000  79  6.125   R   N   IL  CO  60600   N   360 1   N   0
181 F108Q4000181    0   791 N   0   1   P   58  17  100000  58  5.625   R   N   ND  SF  58500   C   360 1   N   0
182 F108Q4000182    0   788 N   0   1   P   78  30  145000  78  5.875   R   N   WI  SF  53500   C   360 2   N   0
183 F108Q4000183    0   747 N   0   1   P   90  52  232000  80  5.625   R   N   ND  SF  58700   N   360 2   N   0
184 F108Q4000184    0   756 N   0   1   P   76  35  276000  76  6   R   N   IL  SF  61000   N   360 2   N   0
185 F108Q4000185    0   757 N   0   1   P   65  10  143000  65  6   C   N   WI  SF  54500   N   360 1   N   0
186 F108Q4000186    0   784 N   0   1   P   48  29  200000  48  5.75    R   N   WA  SF  98800   C   360 2   N   0
187 F108Q4000187    0   785 N   0   1   P   54  17  140000  54  5.875   C   N   KY  SF  40600   N   360 2   N   0
188 F108Q4000188    0   802 N   0   1   P   56  22  83000   56  6.5 R   N   KY  SF  42200   N   360 1   N   0
189 F108Q4000189    0   728 N   0   1   P   95  39  196000  80  5.75    R   N   ND  SF  58100   P   360 2   N   0
190 F108Q4000190    0   728 N   0   1   P   80  23  256000  80  5.875   C   N   IL  SF  60000   C   360 1   N   0
191 F108Q4000191    0   781 N   0   1   S   68  56  230000  68  6   R   N   NC  SF  28100   P   360 2   N   0
192 F108Q4000192    0   775 N   0   1   P   44  45  193000  44  5.75    R   N   CA  SF  96000   C   360 2   N   0
193 F108Q4000193    0   661 N   0   1   P   37  19  91000   37  5.625   R   N   NC  SF  27500   C   360 2   N   0
194 F108Q4000194    0   731 N   0   1   P   77  55  276000  77  5.625   R   N   ND  SF  58000   N   360 1   N   0
195 F108Q4000195    0   768 Y   0   1   P   80  18  76000   80  6   R   Y   MI  SF  48700   P   360 1   N   0
196 F108Q4000196    0   758 N   12  1   P   85  24  81000   85  5.875   R   Y   KS  SF  66600   C   360 2   N   0
197 F108Q4000197    0   760 9   0   1   P   62  32  235000  62  5.75    R   N   MN  SF  56300   C   360 2   N   0
198 F108Q4000198    0   812 N   0   1   S   42  31  100000  42  5.875   R   N   NJ  SF  8200    P   360 2   N   0
199 F108Q4000199    0   752 N   0   1   P   70  31  295000  70  6.25    R   N   NY  SF  12500   C   360 2   N   0
200 F108Q4000200    0   818 N   25  1   P   90  35  65000   90  5.875   R   N   NY  SF  14900   P   360 1   N   0
201 F108Q4000201    0   697 N   0   1   P   68  18  400000  68  6.375   C   N   MT  SF  59900   C   360 2   N   0
202 F108Q4000202    0   689 N   0   1   P   80  44  317000  80  6.125   R   N   NE  PU  68100   N   360 2   N   0
203 F108Q4000203    0   771 N   0   1   P   63  65  280000  63  5.875   R   N   CA  SF  96100   C   360 1   N   0
204 F108Q4000204    0   721 N   0   1   P   53  44  192000  53  5.75    R   N   WA  SF  98800   C   360 2   N   0
205 F108Q4000205    0   783 N   30  1   P   92  30  179000  92  6.375   R   N   MI  SF  49700   N   360 1   N   0
206 F108Q4000206    0   774 N   25  1   P   90  24  144000  90  6.375   R   N   NY  CO  10900   P   360 1   N   0
207 F108Q4000207    0   737 9   0   1   P   80  54  212000  80  5.875   R   N   OH  SF  45000   N   360 2   N   0
208 F108Q4000208    0   794 N   0   1   P   74  17  121000  74  5.875   R   N   AK  SF  99600   C   360 2   N   0
209 F108Q4000209    0   813 N   0   1   P   63  30  315000  63  5.75    R   N   CA  SF  95300   P   360 1   N   0
210 F108Q4000210    0   704 N   0   1   P   20  12  60000   20  5.75    R   Y   OH  SF  45300   N   360 2   N   0
211 F108Q4000211    0   732 N   17  1   P   90  48  200000  90  6   R   N   IL  SF  60400   P   360 2   N   0
212 F108Q4000212    0   779 N   0   1   P   80  22  276000  80  5.625   C   N   MN  SF  55900   P   360 2   N   0
213 F108Q4000213    0   735 N   0   1   P   67  40  60000   67  5.75    R   Y   KY  SF  40300   N   360 1   N   0
214 F108Q4000214    0   719 N   12  1   P   84  48  189000  84  5.875   R   N   KS  SF  66600   C   360 2   N   0
215 F108Q4000215    0   727 Y   0   1   P   47  47  115000  47  6.375   R   N   VA  SF  23100   P   360 2   N   0
216 F108Q4000216    0   708 N   0   1   P   80  40  199000  80  6   R   N   IN  SF  46700   N   360 2   N   0
217 F108Q4000217    0   790 N   0   1   P   77  29  249000  77  5.875   R   N   WI  SF  53100   N   360 2   N   0
218 F108Q4000218    0   731 N   0   1   P   80  25  126000  80  5.625   R   N   NC  SF  27800   N   360 2   N   0
219 F108Q4000219    0   742 N   0   1   P   63  31  137000  63  6.25    R   N   NM  SF  87100   N   360 1   N   0
220 F108Q4000220    1   663 N   25  1   P   95  34  121000  95  6.75    R   N   TX  SF  77600   N   360 2   N   0
221 F108Q4000221    0   757 N   0   1   S   74  19  252000  74  6.125   R   N   IA  CO  51300   N   360 2   N   0
222 F108Q4000222    0   798 N   0   1   P   72  17  210000  72  5.875   R   N   WA  SF  99300   P   360 2   N   0
223 F108Q4000223    0   800 N   0   1   P   80  999 320000  80  5.875   R   N   ID  SF  83600   P   360 1   N   0
224 F108Q4000224    0   745 N   0   1   P   42  34  240000  42  5.875   C   N   MI  SF  49700   C   360 1   N   0
225 F108Q4000225    0   796 N   0   1   P   80  30  176000  80  5.875   R   N   TX  SF  77600   P   360 2   N   0
226 F108Q4000227    0   795 Y   0   1   P   70  27  328000  70  5.875   R   N   AK  SF  99500   P   360 2   N   0
227 F108Q4000228    0   752 N   0   1   P   77  47  165000  77  5.875   R   N   KY  SF  42100   N   360 1   N   0
228 F108Q4000229    0   761 N   0   1   P   76  49  406000  76  5.625   R   N   CA  SF  95900   C   360 2   N   0
229 F108Q4000230    0   747 N   0   1   I   49  23  102000  49  6.125   R   N   CO  SF  81200   C   360 2   N   0
230 F108Q4000231    0   683 Y   0   1   P   74  14  69000   74  6   R   Y   MI  SF  48700   P   360 2   N   0
231 F108Q4000232    0   804 N   0   1   P   80  60  160000  80  6.25    R   N   IL  SF  62900   P   360 2   N   0
232 F108Q4000233    0   783 N   0   1   P   80  16  194000  80  5.875   R   N   IL  SF  62800   N   360 2   N   0
233 F108Q4000234    0   800 N   0   1   P   39  28  175000  39  6   R   N   CT  SF  6400    N   360 2   N   0
234 F108Q4000235    0   693 N   0   1   P   69  40  00  69  5.875   R   Y   KY  SF  42100   N   360 2   N   0
235 F108Q4000236    0   751 N   25  1   P   90  49  248000  90  5.625   C   N   MN  SF  56000   N   360 2   N   0
236 F108Q4000237    0   790 N   0   1   P   77  22  311000  77  5.875   R   N   RI  SF  2900    N   36
```

I just want to build a simple logistic regression model using trained data and show confusion matrix.

Comment: Remove AllMortage$ from the formula.

Comment: @Roland, still the same errors though I did remove the AllMortgage$

Comment: Please update your question.

Comment: I don't believe you get the warning `'newdata' had 62537 rows but variables found have 208454 rows` with the code you show now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally agree with you on what you are doing with the logistic regression, It is all conceptually right, I do not have the access to your dataset so I cant test the logistic. I suggest you to pay attention on two things (which were the ones that I've Always missed)

1. Convert to 'factor' the Response Variable

When you load the dataset into you R enviroment make sure that the variables that acts as 'response' are factor, so that they take only values either 1 or 0. 
you can do it manually at like this (otherwise you use the **as.factor** function directly in front of the reponse variable in the model):

[How you auto convert to factor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK3et.jpg)

2. do not use abbreviation 
   try to specify all the attributes: in the GLM building:

   `mylogit<-glm(AllMortgage$default ~ AllMortgage$credit_score + AllMortgage$cltv + AllMortgage$dti_ratio + AllMortgage$upb + AllMortgage$ltv + AllMortgage$interest_rate + AllMortgage$loan_term + AllMortgage$num_borrowers,
            data= your.data, subset = training, family=binomial)`

try to specify all the attributes: in the predict function:

```
mylogit.probs<-predict(mylogit,newdata = validation,type="response")
```

Comment: Hi @NiccoloSalvini, thanks for responding! I did change default to a factor, using 

`AllMortgage$default <- as.factor(AllMortgage$default)`

but i'm still getting all the same errors above :(

Comment: try to attach your data with function attach() (attaching a dataset means to have all the variables in your environment, instead of using the '$' selection) . I think R is getting data from the original dataset, and not from the splitted one. Then Now I realize that a R gives you a warning not an error, and it is not a problem, I Always get it when I'm doing the logistic. Try to go Beyond and build the confusion matrix like you were doing, you will get the results.

Comment: Never use `attach`. `glm` will use the data.frame passed to its `data` argument if you don't specify something else in the formula, i.e., don't use `$` in the formula.